# How to create sequence for a number that starts at 100 and increment by 5 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need that the values for a ColumnID, which is a Primary Key, to start at 100 and increment by 5. This condition is asked to be included as a constraint before populating the tables. I already created the tables, I just need to add that constraint. I know I can't use AUTO_INCREMENT because the increase is only by 1. Is there a way to do it in MySQL?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Zirely! The question and the description for it are quite confusing... Can you add more information/details, please? 

E.g. What should the number 100 105 110 represent? Is it a unique `id` (ColumnID) for a row in the table? Or should it just be a list of numbers from say 100 to 1000 with a step of a 5 for some other purposes?

Comment: Check the information about the `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-source.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment), it might help

Comment: Related question: [Is it possible to set auto-increment-increment by 10 for only one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/163248)

Comment: Hello. Yes, the ColumnID is unique, is a Primary Key. this condition is asked to be included as a constraint before populating the tables. I already created the tables, I just need to add that constraint. Thanks! I hope this makes the question clearer and you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not provide any built-in function to create a sequence for a table's rows or columns. But we can generate it via SQL query.

Example:

Let us understand it with the help of the following example. First, we need to create a new table and make sure that there is one column with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute and that too, as PRIMARY KEY.

Execute the below query to create a table:

```
   CREATE TABLE Insects (  
   Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,    
   Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   
   Type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
   Origin VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL   
);
```

Then you can alter your column to start from another value:

```
ALTER TABLE Insects AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

You can check it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9a00e16089aef158ed2ef9b1da52512).

Comment: Wonderful, but what about the requirement to increment by 5? With your solution, the auto increment is still 1 (one). Besides which, it is explicitly stated in the question that _I know I can't use AUTO_INCREMENT_

Comment: According to the MySQL documentation, you can't set custom auto-increment value for a specific table.